# Just install Node 0.12.0 and giving an error once I type 'npm'

Tags: node.js

I am trying to install NodeJS 0.12.0, I am using nvm

1. rm -rf www/lib
2. npm cache clear
3. npm installl
4. nvm install 0.12.0

everything was fine until, then I did:

```
mretana@mretana:~/Documents/Projects/capilleiraclickandgamblemobile$ nvm install 0.12.0
v0.12.0 is already installed.
Now using node v0.12.0
```

I thought: Ok, I have node 0.12.0 running, but then I entered `npm` on the console and I got this:

```
bash: /home/mretana/.nvm/versions/v0.12.0/bin/npm: /home/mretana/.nvm/versions/v0.12.0/bin/node: bad interpreter: Permission denied
```

Comment: What interpreter is it complaining about? (What is `head -n1 /home/mretana/.nvm/versions/v0.12.0/bin/node`)

Comment: Alternately, if node itself is the interpreter, what is `ls -l /home/mretana/.nvm/versions/v0.12.0/bin/node`

Comment: @ComputerDruid this is what I got if I type that on the console:
```-rw-rw-r-- 1 mretana mretana 0 Feb 17 10:18 /home/mretana/.nvm/versions/v0.12.0/bin/node``` what should I do ?

Comment: `chmod +x /home/mretana/.nvm/versions/v0.12.0/bin/node`, probably. How did you get that binary without executable permissions?